# Setting up development stages using gulp / package.json

Tags: json, gulp, package.json, web-development-server

OK, so I am trying a new setup to give me a more efficient way of developing my sites.

At the moment I can only think of 3 stages, development, staging and build

As I'm using gulp, I have been typing **gulp** into Terminal to get started which then creates my build site.

Rather than run the **Gulp** command, I would like to use something like **npm run development**  or **npm run staging** or **npm run build**

I understand by typing **Gulp** it automatically looks for the gulpfile.js file. How do I creat my own files?

I understand its something to do with scripts in the package.json file but I can't workout how.

Here's what I have so far:

```
{
  "name": "Name",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Description",
  "main": "index.html",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "development": "node builds/development.js",
    "staging": "node builds/staging.js",
    "build": "node builds/build.js"
  },
  "author": "Author name here",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "^4.0.2",
  },
  "dependencies": {
  }
}
```

Now when I type 'npm run staging' (being a exact copy of gulpfile.js) I would expect it to start just like if I typed **Gulp**

UPDATE:
Here is my gulpfile

```
// --------------------------------------------
// Gulp Loader
// --------------------------------------------
// Stop having to put gulp. infront of the following
const {
  src,
  dest,
  task,
  watch,
  series,
  parallel
} = require("gulp");

// --------------------------------------------
// Dependencies
// --------------------------------------------

// HTML plugins
var htmlmin = require("gulp-htmlmin");

// CSS / SASS plugins
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var cleanCSS = require('gulp-clean-css');

// Images plugins
// let imagemin = require("gulp-imagemin");
var embedSvg = require("gulp-embed-svg");

// Browser plugins
var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();

// Utility plugins
var plumber = require("gulp-plumber");
var rename = require("gulp-rename");
var cache = require('gulp-cache');
var autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
var shell = require('shelljs');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var del = require("del");
var inject = require('gulp-inject');
var shell = require('shelljs');
var noop = require('gulp-noop');
// --------------------------------------------
// Get Home Folder location
// --------------------------------------------
//Displays Users/User
const homedir = require("os").homedir();
// Needed for next part
var path = require("path");
//Displays Users/User/Documents/Clients/clientname/Projects (This is where I create my client folders)
var pathDir = require("path").resolve(__dirname, "../../");
var pathSrc = require("path").resolve(__dirname, "../../../");
//Display the name of the Clients folder name
var parentFld = path
  .dirname(pathDir)
  .split(path.sep)
  .pop();
var parentDir = path.basename(path.dirname(pathDir));
parentDir = parentFld.replace(/[^\w]/g, "");
parentDir = parentFld.replace(/[^\w]/g, "").toLowerCase();


// BrowserSync
function server(done) {
  browserSync.init({
    proxy: "http://" + parentDir + ".test",
    host: parentDir + ".test",
    open: "external",
    notify: false
  });
  done();
}

// function watcher() {
// Serve files from the root of this project
//  browserSync.init({
//    proxy: "https://" + parentdir + ".test",
// //   host: parentdir + ".test",
// open: "external",
//   https: {
//     key: homedir + "/.config/valet/Certificates/" + parentdir + ".test.key",
//    cert: homedir + "/.config/valet/Certificates/" + parentdir + ".test.crt"
// },
// browser: "Google Chrome Canary",
// notify: false
// });

// --------------------------------------------
// Paths
// --------------------------------------------
var paths = {
  htaccess: {
    src: './source/.htaccess',
    dest: './development/.htaccess',
  },
  html: {
    src: './source/*.html',
    prt: './source/partials/*.html',
    dest: './development/'
  },
  styles: {
    src: 'source/styles/*.css',
    dest: 'development/styles/'
  },
  scripts: {
    src: 'source/scripts/*.js',
    dest: 'development/scripts'
  }
}

// --------------------------------------------
// Tasks
// --------------------------------------------


//Basic task with a log - SHOW $homedir
function home(cb) {
  console.log(fontBld);
  cb()
}
task('default', function () {
  console.log('Hello World!');
});

//Basic task with a log
function ssg(cb) {
  console.log(parentDir);
  cb()
}

// CONSOLE LOG
function console_log(cb) {
  console.log(parentDir);
  cb()
}

function valet_link(cb) {
  shell.mkdir(['development']);
  shell.cd(['./development']);
  if (shell.exec('sudo valet link' + ' ' + parentDir).code !== 0) {
    shell.echo('Error: Git commit failed');
    shell.exit(1);
  }
  shell.cd(['..']);
  cb()
}

// CLEAN
function clean(cb) {
  del.sync(paths.html.dest, {
    force: true
  });
  cb()
}

// HT ACCESS
function htaccess() {
  return src(paths.htaccess.src)
    .pipe(dest(paths.htaccess.dest));
}

// HTML
function html() {
  var injectPartials = src(paths.html.prt, {
    relative: true
  });
  var injectStyles = src([paths.styles.src], {
    relative: true
  });
  var injectScripts = src(paths.scripts.src, {
    relative: true
  });
  return src(paths.html.src)
    .pipe(inject(injectPartials, {
      starttag: '<!-- inject:header:{{ext}} -->',
      transform: function (filePath, file) {
        // return file contents as string
        return file.contents.toString('utf8')
      }
    }))
    .pipe(inject(injectStyles, {
      addRootSlash: false,
      ignorePath: '/source/'
    }))
    .pipe(inject(injectScripts, {
      addRootSlash: false,
      ignorePath: '/source/'
    }))
    .pipe(
      embedSvg({
        root: "./source/images/",
        selectors: ".inline-svg"
      })
    )
    .pipe(dest(paths.html.dest));
}

// CSS
function css() {
  return src(paths.styles.src)

    .pipe(sass({
      outputStyle: 'compressed'
    }))
    .pipe(plumber())
    .pipe(dest(paths.styles.dest))
}

// JS
function js() {
  return src(paths.scripts.src)

    .pipe(
      rename({
        basename: "main",
        suffix: ".min"
      })
    )
    .pipe(plumber())
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(dest(paths.scripts.dest));
}

// IMAGES
function img(done) {
  src(imageSrc + "*")
    .pipe(imagemin())
    .pipe(dest(imageDest));
  done();
}

// FONTS
function fonts(done) {
  src(fontSrc + "*").pipe(dest(fontDest));
  done();
}

function clearCache(done) {
  cache.clearAll();
  done();
}
// --------------------------------------------
// Watch
// --------------------------------------------
function watcher() {
  watch(paths.styles.src).on('change', series(css, browserSync.reload));
  watch(paths.scripts.src).on('change', series(js, browserSync.reload));
  watch(paths.htaccess.src).on('change', series(htaccess, browserSync.reload));
  watch(paths.html.src).on('change', series(html, browserSync.reload));
}

// --------------------------------------------
// Compile
// --------------------------------------------
exports.test = series(clean, html)
exports.log = console_log
exports.valet = valet_link
// --------------------------------------------
// Build
// --------------------------------------------
// CONSOLE LOG
function build_log(cb) {
  console.log("Please either use 'npm run production' or 'npm run development'");
  cb()
}

var compile = series(clean, valet_link, series(html, css, js));

task('default', series(compile, parallel(server, watcher)));
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to create multiple gulp files, you can simply have one gulp.js file and simply call your gulp file in you package.json the way you are already doing like so:

```
"scripts": {
    "gulp": "gulp",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
},
```

Than, on your gulp file you just create your exports like so:

```
exports.development = function devFunction(){ ... };
exports.staging = function stagingFunction(){ ... };
exports.build = function buildFunction(){ ... };
```

You would than run each task, you would call "gulp *task*" like so:

```
gulp development
```

Comment: Thanks, I like this but I can't implement it. I get the following error ```[09:08:58] Starting 'development'...
[09:08:59] The following tasks did not complete: development
[09:08:59] Did you forget to signal async completion?
```

Comment: What does you dev function look like? devFunction() in my example

Comment: Hi, I've just update my question to add my gulpfile.js I've removed everything to do with the environment to make it simpler. How would I use ```exports.development = function devFunction(){ ... };``` with that?

Comment: Any thoughts on this, I cannot for the life of me get this to work?

Comment: Sure, you can create your exports the way you are now, for example: exports.development = series(clean, html);. Adding of course, your development tasks, than you can call you "gulp development" from your terminal

Comment: Thanks, I'll stick to this way then.